# htaccess not working in godaddy

Tags: php, .htaccess

i have host my website in godaddy webserver and i try to use htaccess file but it didin't work please tell me what the solution and help me to make it work

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews 
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

Comment: location of your `.htaccess` file must be root directory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove .php extension with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess)

Comment: could you tell me aboute the exact directory pealse

Answer (score 0):

- Use FileZilla or any other software navigate to the root of the website you want to apply
  these changes.
- Find .htaccess file (Use any editor to edit the file)
- Change it with the following code.

  ```
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^YOURSITE\.com\\index$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.YOURSITE\.com\\index$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
  RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.YOURSITE\.com\/" [R=301,L]

  # Turn mod_rewrite on
  Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

  RewriteBase /


  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [QSA,L]

  # Redirect /product?pid=2 to /product/2
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+product\?pid=([^&\s]+) [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ /product/%1? [R=302,L]
  ```

Comment: try www.yoursite.com/index and see if the page is loading

Comment: the result is :    404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: Kindly share the location of ur .htaccess file

Comment: its the same of my php files

Comment: What is your godaddy hosting plan?

Comment: i don't understand you but i'am using windows server